# order id based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create an orderid based on the id and date like 2011070001

Code:

```
DECLARE @TT TABLE (
orderid as CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(date)) + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(date)) + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar, id),5),
id int IDENTITY(1,1),
date date
)

INSERT INTO @TT VALUES ('2011-06-11 08:43:17.000')
INSERT INTO @TT VALUES ('2011-07-20 08:43:17.000')

SELECT * FROM @TT
```

OUTPUT

> order              id     date
>   201160001    1      2011-06-11
>   201170002    2       2011-07-20

How to insert this temp table into my order table?

Comment: If you already have an `id` and a `date`, then storing this new `orderid` is a duplication of data. You don't need to store it again. Just produce it from the id and date wherever it needs to be *displayed*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just write a insert statement above of your select. But you have to make sure that the columns returning from your select matches the insert columns.

```
DECLARE @TT TABLE (
orderid as CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(date)) + CONVERT(varchar, MONTH(date)) + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(varchar, id),5),
id int IDENTITY(1,1),
date date
)

INSERT INTO @TT VALUES ('2011-06-11 08:43:17.000')
INSERT INTO @TT VALUES ('2011-07-20 08:43:17.000')

INSERT INTO ORDERTABLE
SELECT * FROM @TT
```

Comment: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Order' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.